# .remove().draw() is making variables undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to remove rows with a certain data attribute, but there's always a few rows that are left behind

I narrowed it down to the `.remove().draw()` method itself! How weird is that?! But sure enough, if I add the `.remove().draw()`, all the alerts past a certain point *turn null or undefined*

```
var table = $j('#table_view_subs').DataTable();   

table.rows().eq(0).filter(function(index) { 
  var row = table.row(index);
  var rowdata = row.data();
  alert(rowdata); //suddenly returns undefined

  var data = row.nodes().to$().data();
  alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //suddenly returns null

  var closesttr = table.row($(this).closest("tr").get(0));
  closesttr.remove().draw(); //if I comment this, all the alerts show the right info
});
```

Have you ever seen this before? What can I be doing wrong?

EDIT: After @A. Wolff's comment:

```
 var table = $j('#table_view_subs').DataTable();

 table.rows().every( function ( index, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    var row = table.row(index);
    var rowdata = row.data();
    alert(rowdata); //suddenly returns undefined
    var data = row.nodes().to$().data();
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //suddenly returns null

    var closesttr = table.row($(this).closest("tr").get(0));
    closesttr.remove(); //if I comment this, all the alerts show the right info
 });

 table.draw();
```

EDIT 2: using the filter another way returns `Uncaught TypeError: table.rows(...).filter(...).remove is not a function`

```
table.rows().filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('data-dynamic') === 'true';
}).remove();
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the `remove()` method is causing the issue. try `closesttr.draw()` and see if the alerts still work.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yep, you're right! Do you know something I can do to remove the rows?

Comment: Could you remove them after the filter?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn What do you mean? I only want to remove some, so I need the filter to go 1 by 1 and check if they have a data atribute set to true

Comment: `eq(0)` means only the first one. Is it really the code you are using? Now removing any element inside a loop would make the `index` mismatching any further element if you redraw it. My bet would be you draw it only once, outside `filter` loop

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh that's what it means? I didn't know! I've had a lot of versions of this, but this is my current one, yes. I'm gonna update the question with some changes

Comment: Your new posted code doesn't do anything. `I'm trying to remove rows with a certain data attribute` This is the  relevant code you should post in question. Basically using `filter` on all rows, checking specific data inside `filter` by returning some condition. Removes these rows and redraw the table. e.g: `table.rows().filter(function(){ return $(this).data('someAttribute') === 'someValue';}).remove(); table.draw();`

Comment: @A.Wolff Well... my new posted code should at least remove every single row, right? Since I changed to every instead of filter. Also, thank you, I wasn't using filter like that. I'm gonna try and get back to you! :D

Comment: @A.Wolff Sadly your suggestion raises an exception... This is so strange :(

Comment: Im not familiar with DataTable API. I was guessing it works the jQuery way but apparently you should use something like in posted link answer: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43162/removing-rows-from-a-table-based-on-a-column-value

Comment: @A.Wolff Do you want to post an answer with that code and a link? You got me on the right track and I fiiiiinalllyy finished this :D